# i want to list all Resource in organisations using python function in google cloud

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I went through the official docs of google cloud  but I don't have an idea how to use these to list resources of specific organization by providing the organization id

```
organizations = CloudResourceManager.Organizations.Search()
projects = emptyList()

parentsToList = queueOf(organizations)
while (parent = parentsToList.pop()) {
  // NOTE: Don't forget to iterate over paginated results.
  // TODO: handle PERMISSION_DENIED appropriately.
  projects.addAll(CloudResourceManager.Projects.List(
      "parent.type:" + parent.type + " parent.id:" + parent.id))
  parentsToList.addAll(CloudResourceManager.Folders.List(parent))
}
organizations = CloudResourceManager.Organizations.Search()
projects = emptyList()

parentsToList = queueOf(organizations)
while (parent = parentsToList.pop()) {
  // NOTE: Don't forget to iterate over paginated results.
  // TODO: handle PERMISSION_DENIED appropriately.
  projects.addAll(CloudResourceManager.Projects.List(
      "parent.type:" + parent.type + " parent.id:" + parent.id))
  parentsToList.addAll(CloudResourceManager.Folders.List(parent))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview) for this. I wrote this code for performing a sink in BigQuery.

```
import os

from google.cloud import asset_v1
from google.cloud.asset_v1.proto import asset_service_pb2


def asset_to_bq(request):

    client = asset_v1.AssetServiceClient()
    parent = 'organizations/{}'.format(os.getEnv('ORGANIZATION_ID'))
    output_config = asset_service_pb2.OutputConfig()
    output_config.bigquery_destination.dataset = 'projects/{}}/datasets/{}'.format(os.getEnv('PROJECT_ID'),
                                                                                   os.getEnv('DATASET'))

    output_config.bigquery_destination.table = 'asset_export'
    output_config.bigquery_destination.force = True

    response = client.export_assets(parent, output_config)

    # For waiting the finish
    # response.result()
    # Do stuff after export
    return "done", 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asset_to_bq('')
```

Be careful is you use it, the sink must be done in an empty/not existing table or set the `force` to true.

In my case, some minutes after the Cloud Scheduler that trigger my function and extract the data to BigQuery, I have a Scheduled Query into BigQuery that copy the data to another table, for keeping the history.

*Note: It's also possible to configure an extract in Cloud Storage if you prefer.*

I hope that is a starting point for you and for achieving what do you want to do.

Comment: hey @guillaume blaquiere , i am also on working cloudassetinventory and I am exporting assets in big query and GCS but at the project level. Now I can export assets at the organization level, thanks for your help.

Comment: i want to list project, project. name,folder.id and I also want to specify the organization id, please review my latest comment..thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am able to list the project but I also want to list the folder and resources under folder and folder.name and tags and i also want to specify the organization id to resources information from a specific organization

```
import os
from google.cloud import resource_manager
def export_resource (organizations):


    client = resource_manager.Client()

    for project in client.list_projects():
        print("%s, %s" % (project.project_id, project.status))
```

Comment: So from what I can understand you managed to answer this question. If you have further questions, it's better to open a new question for them.